# msysgit: option to not set hidden flag

Tags: windows, git, file-permissions, hidden, msysgit

I'm using msysgit and for files starting with a slash, e.g. `.classpath` it automatically sets the *hidden* flag which makes it impossible for IDEs to overwrite it. How to prevent setting this *hidden* flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git config core.hidedotfiles "false"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add --global to make this the default behaviour for all new repos:

```
git config --global core.hidedotfiles "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) when setting the `core.hidedotfiles`, before creating new repositories.

Before, "`git init`" forgot to read platform-specific repository configuration, which made Windows port to ignore settings of `core.hidedotfiles`, for example.

See [commit 2878533](https://github.com/git/git/commit/287853392a2bb9199c9fa567d8bc95b7c1275139) (11 Mar 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6364386](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63643865d2505bd7586ace4481d5f1f373dacf2c), 16 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `mingw`: respect `core.hidedotfiles = false` in `git init` again

> This is a brown paper bag.
> When adding the tests, we actually failed to verify that the config variable is heeded in `git init` at all.
> And when changing the original patch that marked the .git/ directory as hidden after reading the config, it was lost on this developer that the new code would use the `hide_dotfiles` variable before the config was read.

> The fix is obvious: read the `(limited, pre-init)` config *before*
> creating the `.git/` directory.

> Please note that we cannot remove the identical-looking `git_config()` call from `create_default_files()`: we create the `.git/` directory between those calls.
> If we removed it, and if the parent directory is in a Git worktree, and if that worktree's `.git/config` contained any `init.templatedir` setting, we would all of a sudden pick that up.

> This fixes [git-for-windows#789](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/789)

---

This is more robust with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), where some leaks are plugged.

See [commit 68ffe09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68ffe095a25b4aba1d6aa1386318ddc8dadcf8c2), [commit 64cc539](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64cc539fd2f8e02f39cfae21e9523da2532c0467), [commit 0171dbc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0171dbcb428739e59440ccdf2d9470d8782f51be) (21 Mar 2021), and [commit 04fe4d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04fe4d75faa237813960f8dcd45a91bd445de235), [commit e4de450](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4de4502e6e32d5ce71fa6fcfc0703a4be411eb7), [commit aa1b639](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa1b63971ab4e7d1f603c87f2137605249580272), [commit 0c45427](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c4542738e626b7af12bcc13673964c98a6eb68b), [commit e901de6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e901de68166a09737110a7e62c23230e648af5ec), [commit f63b888](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f63b88867a8f87d7f8442b2dc2deb38c720449bc) (14 Mar 2021) by [Andrzej Hunt (`ahunt`)](https://github.com/ahunt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 642a400](https://github.com/git/git/commit/642a40019c99a42f5f4ed4f3e52b9ab92cd75fe7), 07 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`init`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4de4502e6e32d5ce71fa6fcfc0703a4be411eb7): remove `git_init_db_config()` while fixing leaks
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Andrzej Hunt</sup>

> The primary goal of this change is to stop leaking `init_db_template_dir`.
> This leak can happen because:
>
> 1. `git_init_db_config()` allocates new memory into `init_db_template_dir` without first freeing the existing value.
> 2. `init_db_template_dir` might already contain data, either because: 2.1 `git_config()` can be invoked twice with this callback in a single process - at least 2 allocations are likely.
>    2.2 A single `git_config()` allocation can invoke the callback multiple times for a given key (see further explanation in the function docs) - each of those calls will trigger another leak.
>
> The simplest fix for the leak would be to `free(init_db_template_dir)` before overwriting it.
> Instead we choose to convert to fetching init.templatedir via `git_config_get_value()` as that is more explicit, more efficient, and avoids allocations (the returned result is owned by the config cache, so we aren't responsible for freeing it).
>
> If we remove `init_db_template_dir,` `git_init_db_config()` ends up being responsible only for forwarding `core.*` config values to `platform_core_config()`.
> However `platform_core_config()` already ignores `non-core.*` config values, so we can safely remove `git_init_db_config()` and invoke `git_config()` directly with `platform_core_config()` as the callback.
>
> The `platform_core_config` forwarding was originally added in:
>
> - [2878533](https://github.com/git/git/commit/287853392a2bb9199c9fa567d8bc95b7c1275139) (`mingw`: respect `core.hidedotfiles = false` in git-init again, 2019-03-11, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63643865d2505bd7586ace4481d5f1f373dacf2c) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffac537e6cbbf934b08745a378932722df287a53))
> - And I suspect the potential for a leak existed since the original implementation of `git_init_db_config` in: [90b4518](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90b45187ba51a15c8a80680597240e32421f53bb) ("Add `init.templatedir` configuration variable.", 2010-02-17, Git v1.7.1-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90a2bf9ca155c8e0e43d9e30197d9562dd02ea96))